# sqlalchemy statement attribute does not exist for some reason

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy

I'm new to sqlalchemy and am trying to print/log the actual delete query that is executed by sqlalchemy when the following is executed:

```
delete_query = mdb_session.query(PendingConfig).filter(PendingConfig.id == config.id).delete()
```

I have looked at a bunch of other stackoverflow posts and the solution suggested is doing this:

```
print str(delete_query.statement)
```

But this doesn't work since `statement` attribute doesn't exist in my `delete_query` object, and I confirmed this by changing the above print code to the following:

```
if hasattr(delete_objs, 'statement'):
   print(str(delete_query.statement))
else:
   print("statement doesn't exist.")
```

In the above, the else line is executed. So basically `statement` attribute isn't existing for me. Why ??? .... Also if I do simply `print(str(delete_query))`, it prints just either `0` or `1`. I don't know why.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete), `delete()` returns the number of items deleted.

Comment: Thanks, but my main question was why `statement` isn't defined inside `delete_query`.

Comment: `delete_query` is an integer, because that's what `delete()` returns.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. So then how can I get the delete query that sqlalchemy executes when the aforementioned command is executed ?